# Are Brownian motion correlations preserved under a measure change?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, cross-variation

Let $W$ and $B$ be two Brownian motions with $\text{d}\langle W, B\rangle_t = \rho \text{d}t$ under some probability measure $\mathbb{P}$, where $\rho$ is a constant.

Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be an equivalent measure to $\mathbb{P}$. Does  $\text{d}\langle W, B\rangle_t = \rho \text{d}t$  under $\mathbb{Q}$? I think this is true by Girsanov?

Comment: "I think this is true by Girsanov?" Could you expand on your "by Girsanov"? Because already $E_Q(\langle W,B\rangle_t)=\rho t=E_P(\langle W,B\rangle_t)$ seems to fail...

Comment: Under $Q$, $dW = dW^Q + \mu_1 dt$, where $\mu_1$ a drift from measure change. The same is true for $dB = dB^Q + \mu_2 dt$. For some reason, I think $\langle W^Q, B^Q\rangle = \rho t$, which must be wrong?

Comment: @Did I think I should perhaps makes it clear that $\rho$ is a constant. I believe my assertion is true under this setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as the measures are equivalent, then it all works out. From the definition of quadratic variation we require convergence in probability but it doesn't matter about which measure we use so long as they are equivalent, which you assume. Hence, it follows that under either measure $\mathbb{P}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ (using the notation in your comment),

$$dW^{\mathbb{P}} = dW^{\mathbb{Q}} + \mu_1 dt\; \text{ and } \;dB^{\mathbb{P}} = dB^{\mathbb{Q}} + \mu_2 dt$$ implies that $$\text{d}\langle W^{\mathbb{P}}, B^{\mathbb{P}}\rangle_t = \text{d}\langle W^{\mathbb{Q}}, B^{\mathbb{Q}}\rangle_t = \rho \text{d}t,$$
where the first equality is by invariance of the quadratic variation under any measure.